# How to read Azure Diagnostics data

Tags: azure

I have Azure Diagnostics setup and logging into all the WAD tables. 
How do I suppose to read all that logs? I have the Azure Storage Explorer, but I don't see how it can be useful and the logs also are loaded with considerable amount of garbage. Is there any way to view the diagnostics data in more sensible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will either have to write yourself a parsing tool to read all the data, or you can purchase something like Cerebrata's [diagnostics tool](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/) to interpret it.  Unfortunately, the data in storage is just raw data and there is no interpretation.

Comment: When 'doing it yourself': filtering on the Timestamp column is very slow for large amounts of data. Use the RowKey for fast date/time-filtering, as described here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/.

Comment: I think you mean the PartitionKey - that is what is keyed for time ranges.  RowKey is a role/instance discriminator.